# Tftpd64 unable to transfer file to client

Tags: windows, networking, file-transfer, tftp

I am using **Tftpd64** as server for transferring file to client.

Now when client request the file then i see below error in log viewer window of Tftpd64.

```
Connection received from 2a01:7e00:e000:11c:3546:7805:766:7110 on port 61445 [23/06 11:50:44.967]
Read request for file <test.ota>. Mode octet [23/06 11:50:44.967]
OACK: <blksize=1200,timeout=5,> [23/06 11:50:44.967]
Using local port 61801 [23/06 11:50:44.967]
File <test.ota> : error 10054 in system call recv An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. [23/06 11:50:45.131]
```

Is any one have idea about above error?

Also i disabled the firewall in my PC but still getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am able to make **Tftpd64** server up and running. I made below changes.

1. Enabled Windows Firewall.
2. Create rule for Tftp server (Widnows firewall->Advance settings->Inbound Rules->New Rule) to allow connection and apply rule for domain, public and private.